# How do I compare correlation coefficients of the same variables across different groups?

Tags: correlation, hypothesis-testing

I am testing the correlation between Variable A and Variable B by gender and marital status.

So I have the coefficients for males and females and single, married and other.

I want to compare the correlation coefficient of male with female.

Similarly, I want to compare the correlation coefficient of single with marrried and with other.

Finally, I want to compare the correlation coefficient of single male with single female, married male with married female and other male and other female. I have these coefficients too.

**What is the easiest way of making this comparison?**

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to show that the (linear) relationship between a variable A and a variable B is stronger for one group than for another? If the answer is yes, then I would go for a regression analysis.

Suppose that there are two continuous variables $X$ and $Y$, and a group variable called $\rm GENDER$ that is equal to 1 for men and equal to 0 for women. I would like to know if the relation between $X$ and $Y$ is different for men than for women. I would then run the following linear regression model:

$$Y = a + b\times X + c\times \text{GENDER}+ d\times\text{GENDER}*X $$

I would then test the joint hypothesis if the coefficients $c$ and $d$ are equal to zero. If this hypothesis is rejected, then I would conclude that there are differences between men and women.

What do you think?

*EDIT: I will add some more explanation, as requested, but I am afraid that this will take us too far away rom the original question ...*

I have taken the original problem, and I have tried to give it some structure. More precisely, I have modeled the continuous variable Y as a function of another continuous variable X and a discrete variable called GENDER. The functional form chose here is a linear one. The lower case letters represent the parameters of the line.

In fact, the above equation looks like one line, but it contains two: one for men and one for women. The parameter a is the intercept for women, (a+c) is the intercept for men, b is the slope for women, and (b+d) is he slope for men.

The parameters c and d mirror the gender differences, or more generally speaking the differences between the two groups. I have used gender for illustrative purposes, but you can replace it by what you want: color, species, marital status, ... Thus, if these two parameters (c and d) are simultaneously equal to zero, there is no (apparent) difference between the two groups, and thus the relation between X and Y is the same for the two groups.

Comment: (+1) It's always a pleasure to read your answers.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but can you please further explain (with an example, if possible) how I need to interpret the different parts in the formula (e.g. what is "a" etc.).

Comment: @Jasty Looks like some independent reading would help you.  You might start online with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and then move to an intro text on regression.

Comment: Would the Fisher's z transformation be an option here for comparing the coefficients?

Comment: @whuber: +1 for your last advice. Nevertheless I will try to add some explanation to my reply.

Comment: While @lejohn's regression approach is probably more elegant, the Fisher's Z comparisons should work just fine and that's probably an easier way.

Comment: I concur with rolando2. The above proposal checks if regression slopes (and levels, the means) are same in two gender groups. But the question was about comparing correlation coeffitients which is not the same as comparing regression coefficients. @Jasty you may look at  http://www.jessicagrahn.com/uploads/6/0/8/5/6085172/comparecorrcoeff.doc for Fisher's z-comparison.