# p-value of an Average Correlation Coeficient

Tags: correlation, p-value

I have several Pearson correlation coefficients with their corresponding p-values. But I need an Average Correlation Coefficient. To calculate it, I've used the Fisher z transformation mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15021/working-with-correlation-coefficients). But, probably due to my lack of knowledge, I didn't find a way to compute a p-value for this average correlation coefficient.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by an average correlation coefficient? Is this the mean of several correlations?

Comment: Perhaps the answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You might just want to calculate the confidence interval.

$Z_r$ has a nearly normal distribution with variance

$$s_z^2 = 1 / n - 3.$$

Using these statistics we can construct a level $C$ confidence interval for the population value

$$Z_r \pm z^* / \sqrt{n - 3}$$

where $z^*$ is the critical value from the normal distribution such that the area between $-z^*$ and $z^*$ is equal to $C$.