# Averaging correlation values from data with multiple levels?

Tags: correlation, multilevel-analysis

At least two questions ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55930/p-value-of-an-average-correlation-coeficient/55936#55936)) have addressed the question of how to handle the analysis of multiple correlations.  I would like to extend this question to the case of data that has multiple levels (say as a relatively straightforward case correlations between personality traits X1, X2, and X3 on trait Y as nested within 40 people).  How then would average correlations be best calculated (and tested for significance) on the understanding that a) the scales have been appropriately coded such that sign does matter and b) that the level of inference desired is to the typical person?  Would the optimal analysis be in the family of intraclass correlations, or is this something else entirely?