# Significance of average correlation coefficients

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, standard-error, pooling

I am using fMRI data (n=25) to predict performance on a behavioral task. At each of 12 time points, I train a linear model on data from n-1 subjects and use this model to predict the left-out subject's performance during a different period of time. For example, I use neural data at time point 1 to predict performance during time window A, and data at time point 2 to predict performance during time window B, etc. For each time point, after leaving each subject out once, I perform Spearman's rank correlation on the observed and predicted values.

This gives me a correlation coefficient at each of my time points. I want to report the average prediction across all of my time points, so I Fisher transformed these r values, averaged the resulting z scores, then transformed the average back to an r value. Is this okay to do since my correlations were all computed within the same group of subjects? Based on previous questions I *think* this is right but please correct me if I'm wrong.

My next question is about how to report the significance of this average r. Is this possible? [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55930/p-value-of-an-average-correlation-coeficient) answer leads me to believe that reporting a confidence interval would be better, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this, or if it's okay because, again, my correlations were computed from data collected at different times from the same group of subjects.

Comment: I don't see any problem for the sake of correlation estimation, but calculating its standard error might be trickier. Good question!

Comment: Although in some cases it may be meaningful to average a set of correlations, as suggested at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019, in other cases the results would be nonsensical (as I argue in a comment at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values/8023#comment13152_8023). Given that you have the original data, there are better ways to proceed (as suggested in many of the related threads).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your point, but am unsure how to proceed. It seems that in this case concatenating and then correlating all of the predicted and observed values would be inappropriate, and I don't completely understand the regression approach you describe [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values/8023#comment13152_8023). Would this be the approach to take if I do want positives and negatives to cancel (maybe what I want is the mean standardized slope mentioned in the comment following yours)?