# Average of correlations over time

Tags: correlation, mean

I currently work on my bachelor's thesis and analyse the correlation between 13 countries over a time period of 117 years. I built a correlation table and now want to say somethin about the average correlation over time. I divided the full sample into three subperiods of different size. Now two questions came up:

1. Is it possible to simply compute the mean for each period by averaging the single correlation coefficients? Or is it analogue to this: [Working with correlation coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15021/working-with-correlation-coefficients)
2. When Building the weighted average of the three subperiods, should it equal the average of the full sample? (currently not the case)

Comment: You estimated the correlation between each pair of countries for the 117 years, this is your "mean" correlation. Now you want to do the same thing, except that you will divide the data into periods?

Comment: My Intention is to build the average correlation across countries. I am wondering if this is done by simply computing the mean of the pairwise correlations derived before.

Comment: Some people do not like that, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you that helped! However, the so computed averages for the subperiods do not equal the average of the full sample, is this correct?

Comment: Could you explain how you might interpret such an "average correlation over time"?  That might help us understand what kind of an average you are looking for.

Comment: I inteded to use the average correlation of the full sample to describe the general co-movement. The subperiods are proxys for different patterns. In order to analyse  the development of synchronization over time I wanted to compute an average of the pairwise correlation coefficients for each subperiod. But the averages of the subperiods dont average to the average for the full sample. Should they? The averages are computed by using the Fisher transformation. Hope this helps!